# Scala type bounds =:=

Tags: scala, type-bounds

While this compiles:

```
  implicit class Container[T](val value:T) extends AnyVal{
    def addInt(x:Int)(implicit ev:T=:=Int) = value+x
  }
```

This complains about type mismatch, expected `T`, actual `Int`, as if it ignores the type bound.

```
  implicit class Container[T](val value:T=>Int) extends AnyVal{
    def addInt(x:Int)(implicit ev:T=:=Int) = value(x)
  }
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your type constraint is backwards, actually. `T =:= Int` provides implicit evidence that `T` is `Int`, but *not exactly* that `Int` is `T`. If you look at the declaration if `=:=`, you'll see that it only goes one way:

```
sealed abstract class =:=[From, To] extends (From => To) with Serializable
```

Your first example works because `value` is a `T`, and the constraint is `T =:= Int`, which implicitly converts `T` to `Int`. But for the second example, we need to feed a `T` to `value: T => Int`, so we need the other direction.

This works:

```
implicit class Container[T](val value: T => Int) extends AnyVal {
    def addInt(x: Int)(implicit ev: Int =:= T) = value(x)
}
```

The reason why your second example using `Int <:< T` also works is because `<:<` provides the implicit conversion from `Int => T`.

Answer (score 0):

Oh probably the issue is the contra-variance of the function. This works now:

```
implicit class Container[T](val value:T=>Int) extends AnyVal{
    def addInt(x:Int)(implicit ev:Int<:<T) = value(x)
  }
```